# Image not appearing in jbutton with wordGen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

The image isn't being painted when this is run with WordGen, how do i fix this? 
When I run this without wordgen I can get the image to appear. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong since i'm not getting any errors.
Any help is appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

    public class tfot extends JComponent{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public static void main(final String[] args) {      




SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showGUI(args);
                }
            });
        }

        public static void showGUI(String[] args) {
            JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
            JButton okButton = new JButton("Did You Know?"); 
            okButton.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 100));
            final JLabel jLab = new JLabel();
            okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    jLab.setText(wordGen());

                }
            });
            JPanel content = new JPanel();
            content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            content.add(displayPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            content.add(okButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            content.add(jLab, BorderLayout.NORTH);

           JFrame window = new JFrame("Window");
            window.setContentPane(content);
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.setSize(800, 600);
            window.setLocation(400, 300);
            window.setVisible(true);
        }
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                g.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Pictures/background1.png"), 0, 0, this);

            }


        public static String wordGen() {

            String[] wordListOne = {"generic text","hi",}; 



            int oneLength = wordListOne.length;

            int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * oneLength);

            String phrase = wordListOne[rand1] + " ";
            return phrase;
        }

    }
```

Comment: 1: Don't load resources within the `paint` method; 2: Where is `Pictures/background1.png` stored? 3: You never actually add `tfot` to anything that would be capable of painting it...

Comment: http://gyazo.com/c7a90ddf569594f41727bf4a8da6cecc

Comment: Then how should i render the image with toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

## First...

Don't load resources or perform long running tasks within the paint methods, these may be called a number of times in quick succession.  Instead, load the images before hand and paint them as needed...

```
public Tfot() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    try {
        background = ImageIO.read(new File("pictures/background1.png"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (background != null) {
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Generally, you are discouraged from overriding `paint` and instead should use `paintComponent`, lots of reasons, but generally, this is where the background is painted...

## Second...

You need to add `Tfot` to something that is displayable, otherwise it will never be painted

```
JFrame window = new JFrame("Window");
window.setContentPane(new Tfot());
window.add(content);
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.setSize(800, 600);
window.setLocation(400, 300);
window.setVisible(true);
```

## Thrid...

`JPanel` by default is not transparent, you need to set it's `opaque` property to `false`

```
JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
displayPanel.setOpaque(false);
//...
JPanel content = new JPanel();
content.setOpaque(false);
```

Then it will allow what ever is below it to show up (ie, the background image)

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

## Fourth...

You need to learn the language basics for embarking on advance topics like GUI and custom painting, without this basic knowledge, this topics will bite you hard.

You need to declare `background` as a instance field of the class `Tfot`

```
private BufferedImage background;
public Tfot() {
```

**Updated - Fully runnable example**

[image: DidYouKnow]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Tfot extends JComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                showGUI(args);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void showGUI(String[] args) {
        JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
        displayPanel.setOpaque(false);
        JButton okButton = new JButton("Did You Know?");
        okButton.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 100));
        final JLabel jLab = new JLabel();
        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jLab.setText(wordGen());

            }
        });
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setOpaque(false);
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        content.add(displayPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        content.add(okButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        content.add(jLab, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        Tfot tfot = new Tfot();
        tfot.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        tfot.add(content);

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Window");
        window.setContentPane(tfot);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(800, 600);
        window.setLocation(400, 300);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    private BufferedImage background;

    public Tfot() {
        try {
            background = ImageIO.read(new File("Pictures/background1.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);

    }

    public static String wordGen() {

        String[] wordListOne = {"generic text", "hi",};

        int oneLength = wordListOne.length;

        int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * oneLength);

        String phrase = wordListOne[rand1] + " ";
        return phrase;
    }

}
```

Comment: I did that and it didn't like background as eclipse errored every background 
http://pastebin.com/QnivUG1D

Comment: *"as eclipse errored every background"* - What does that mean?  The answer is based on running code I wrote to solve the problem

Comment: Did you think to create an instance variable `background`?  Since `ImageIO.read` returns a `BufferedImage`, maybe of that type?

Comment: How would i do that, I don't have much experience with imageio.

Comment: `ImageIO` is irrelevent.  Do you know how to declare a instance field for a class? If not, you have bigger problems

Comment: So, with out knowing the language basics, you've jumped in the deep end, with the sharks and gone straight for GUI programming, which is difficult enough AND custom painting, which is one of the most advanced topics of the graphics API...I'd take a step back and have a closer look at [Learning the Java Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)

Comment: Based on what I understand of your code, it should run (certainly does for me), consider putting in some System.out.println statements to display messages at various points in the code to see where the code is running to

Comment: The problem lies in the:
    public static void showGUI(String[] args) {
         JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
         JButton okButton = new JButton("title?"); 
         okButton.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 100));
         final JLabel jLab = new JLabel();
         okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 jLab.setText(wordGen());
                 System.out.println("2");

Comment: So the file you're trying to read isn't where you're saying it is

Comment: Yea that was a mistake on my part but nothing opens up and the console  only returns what i printed in everything but that section.

Comment: Well, I have a full runnable example, which is simply your code plus my suggested modifications...